# PHP: How to fix my preg_replace code

Tags: php, preg-replace

If I have a string like

```
$str = "Hello [Page 1] World [Page 23] Hello [Page 35] World [Page 624]";
```

And I want to remove all instances of "[Page #]"

How would I go about doing that?

Here's what I've got so far...

```
preg_replace('[Page [0-9]]', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `[` and `]` are class delimiters. When you want to use them as literals you need to escape them (prefix with `\`) first. So:

```
/\[Page [0-9]+\]/i
```

is probably your best bet. Surround the pattern with `/`, add a `+` to your number range to match "1+ numbers", and the final `i` means case-insensitive match (P or p in "Page") (remove if that's not your intent).

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/\\[Page [0-9]+\\]/', '', $str)
```

Comment: need to escape the [ to match them. the plus means one or more.

Comment: You also need to add a delimiter eg /pattern/ or @pattern@

Comment: and double escape to get the escape into the pattern. corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\[Page \d+\]/
```

works, too. \d is shorthand for number-chars.